# whoami in python

Tags: python, posix

What is the best way to find out the user that a python process is running under?

I could do this:

```
name = os.popen('whoami').read()
```

But that has to start a whole new process.

```
os.environ["USER"]
```

works sometimes, but sometimes that environment variable isn't set.

Answer (score 103):

```
import getpass
print(getpass.getuser())
```

See the documentation of the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) module.

> getpass.getuser()
>
> Return the “login name” of the user. Availability: Unix, Windows.
>
> This function checks the environment variables LOGNAME, USER,
> LNAME and USERNAME, in order, and
> returns the value of the first one
> which is set to a non-empty string. If
> none are set, the login name from the
> password database is returned on
> systems which support the pwd module,
> otherwise, an exception is raised.

Comment: great, but anyone can tamper with these variables. NEVER rely on this as a secure way to get the user's username. you have been warned.

Answer (score 20):

This should work under Unix.

```
import os
print(os.getuid()) # numeric uid
import pwd
print(pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())) # full /etc/passwd info
```

Comment: This solution only works on Unix see http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html?highlight=pwd

Comment: Works on my linux box, i had the same answer as this one but will delete it as i was 2 minutes later ;-)

Comment: getpass.getuser() uses this approach as a fallback if it cannot find the username in the environment variables.

Comment: @Ayman: I find it better to rely on os.getuid than environment variables to figure out who I am. Environment variables are untrustworthy, especially if security matters.

Comment: @Nadia: Aye, it probably doesn't work on Windows, but the question is tagged posix, and os.getuid and pwd.getpwuid are both part of Posix.

Comment: @NadiaAlramli he knows. he said so in the answer.